# JS : karma rollup empty bundle

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner, rollupjs

[UPDATE]

The original title of this post was : "Bad karma, lost data" and standed for the mind word play, much more for the rimes than for a real fact. So I decided to alter it, for the sake of correctness and courtesy.

[UPDATE]

Hi there, I've a very classical program directory strcture:

```
dist/
karam.conf.js
node_modules/
package.json
rollup.config.js
src/
    fp/
        list.js     # imports maybe.js
        matbe.js
test/
    fp/
        list.specs.js
        maybe.specs.js
```

I'm trying to preprocess the tests with rollup. My karma.conf.js is just like :

```
# karma.conf.js
const buble = require('@rollup/plugin-buble')
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve').default

// console.log({ resolve })

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath : '',

        files: [
            { 
                pattern: 'src/fp/*.js', watched: true 
            },{ 
                pattern: 'test/fp/*.specs.js', watched: true
            }
        ],

        watch: true,

        preprocessors: {
            'src/fp/*.js': ['rollup2'],
            'test/fp/*.specs.js': ['rollup2']
        },

        rollup2Preprocessor: {
            output: {
                name: 'fptest',
                format: 'iife'
            },
            plugins: [
                buble(),
                resolve()
            ]
        }
   });
}
```

When I start karma, with npm or from CLI with "karma start --log-level debug", I get 4 empty bundles and get the error message "Error during file loading or preprocessing
TypeError: output is not iterable".

So I could not test my program properly.

What's happening and how to fix that ?

Thanks for replies, Regards.

Comment: can you provide a sample of `Queen` and the test for that class?

Comment: I just pushed code ! repo is : https://github.com/hefeust/colorchess-v2

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your module loader, I suggest using a karma plugin like `karma-rollup-preprocessor` to bundle your module before running tests. This will bundle and wire-up your modules properly for testing.

And you don't need to specify all your files under files array.

```
files: [
    'test/**/*.js'
],
```